# How to explain the time dilation effect non-mathematically (without Lorentz transformation)?

Tags: special-relativity, time, time-dilation

I read many good and rigorous mathematical explanations of the time dilation effect, but I didn't see any non-mathematical explanations.

Is it possible to explain the time dilation effect non-mathematically? How?

Comment: You can derive it via Minkowski diagrams. Would that be enough of non-mathematical for you?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my graphical, non-algebraic motivation which uses the Relativity principle and the Speed-of-Light principle,
based on my https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/relativity-on-rotated-graph-paper-a-graphical-motivation/ (see also my paper "Introducing relativity on rotated graph paper" as Ch 7 of [Teaching Einsteinian Physics in Schools (Kersting & Blair, 9781003161721)](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/edit/10.4324/9781003161721/teaching-einsteinian-physics-schools-magdalena-kersting-david-blair) ).

(You can play with the visualizations at https://www.geogebra.org/m/kvfsq664 .
Uncheck "showGrid".)

---

Suppose 2 seconds (according to each inertial observer's wristwatch) after they meet,
they each send a light-signal to the other observer.
According to the Relativity principle, they should agree on when they receive the signal from the other inertial observer.

Let's suppose a relative-velocity of $v/c=(3/5)$.

Alice uses the ticks of her **longitudinal light clock** (where the mirror separation is parallel to the direction of relative-motion) to draw Bob's worldline on a spacetime diagram.
We want to draw the ticks (the light-clock diamonds) on Bob's longitudinal light clock.

*Note that this construction does not use the more common transverse light clock, and it does not appeal to a second spatial direction. This construction lies in the (1+1)-Minkowski spacetime diagram.*

Assuming the Speed-of-light principle (so all light signals are at 45-degrees)

1. ...and Absolute Time

   [image: RRGP-robphy-motivation-absolute-time]

   Alice receives Bob's signal at 3.2.
   Bob receives Alice's signal at 5.
   This disagrees with the Relativity principle.

   Bob's ticks are too short, they have to be longer
   so that Alice receives the signal later (greater than 3.2)
   and Bob receives the signal earlier (less than 5).

   **The Relativity principle implies "time-dilation".. but by how much?**

   (If you draw in Bob's light-clock mirror worldlines
   *[determined by the intersection of the light-cones of ticks 0, 1, and 2]*
   , their separation is shorter than Alice's... but it is too short.)
2. ...and Absolute Space

   [image: RRGP-robphy-motivation-absolute-space]

   (So, we draw in Bob's light-clock mirror worldlines to have the same separation as Alice's. Draw the resulting light-clock signals to determine Bob's ticks.)

   Alice receives Bob's signal at 5.
   Bob receives Alice's signal at 3.2.
   This also disagrees with the Relativity principle.

   Bob's ticks are too long, they have to be shorter
   so that Alice receives the signal earlier (less than 5)
   and Bob receives the signal later (greater than 3.2).

   The separation between Bob's mirror worldlines is too large.

   **The Relativity principle implies "length-contraction".. but by how much?**
3. ...and some other condition (which turns out to be the equality of their clock-diamond areas).

   [image: RRGP-robphy-motivation-absolute-interval]

   *(So, by tuning the separation of Bob's light-clock mirror worldlines,
   we can draw the resulting light-clock signals to determine Bob's ticks.
   We tune the separation to be shorter than Alice's
   until we obtain equal reception times.)*

   We find...
   Alice receives Bob's signal at 4.
   Bob receives Alice's signal at 4.
   (Note that $(4)^2=(3.2)(5)$, so that 4 is the geometric mean of 3.2 and 5.)
   This now agrees with the Relativity principle,

   and we get the correct factors for time-dilation and length-contraction.


   By re-checking "showGrid", one can see that Bob's light-clock diamond
   must have an **area equal** to that of Alice's light-clock diamond.
   This is essentially the **"invariance of the square-interval"**.

   [image: RRGP-robphy-motivation-absolute-interval-rotated-graph-paper]

   Bob's diamond is Alice's diamond stretched by a factor of $k=2$ in one direction
   and shrunk by that factor in the other direction, thus preserving the area (which is needed since a boost has determinant equal to one).
   It can be shown that $k=2$ is the Doppler-factor corresponding to $v/c=(3/5)$ using $k=\sqrt{\frac{1+v}{1-v}}$.

"Converting from the grid based on Alice's light-clock diamonds
to the grid based on Bob's light-clock diamonds"
is essentially the **Lorentz transformation.**

---

Try it for $v/c=(4/5)$. What is the corresponding $k$-factor?

(Rational $k$-factors lead to nicer arithmetic with Pythagorean triples. Useful: $v=\frac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}$.)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to think about this is to really emphasize that all observers see all light as traveling at the speed of c - as measured from their own position. c is the absolute here. (Just for example, if one observer is running toward you holding a flashlight, he sees the light leaving him at c, but you see it as coming toward you at c.)

The only way to make all this work is to have clocks run differently for different observers. Beyond that explanation, we’ll need math.

Answer (score 3):

A clock is something which produces a series of events spaced equally in time.

So here is a clock consisting of two mirrors which are parallel to one another and there is a pulse of light bouncing between the mirrors.
To an observer stationary relative to the "clock", the interval of time (tick) is defined as the time it takes for the pulse of light to start at mirror $A$, travel a distance $\ell$ to reach mirror $B$ where it is reflected and then travels a distance $\ell$ to reach mirror $A$ again.

[image]

Now what happens if the "clock" is moving relative to the observer as shown in the right-hand diagram.
The interval of time (tick) to an observer looking at the moving "clock" is defined as the time it takes for the pulse of light to start at mirror $A$, travel a distance $L$ to reach mirror $B'$ which has moved relative to the observer where it is reflected and then travels a distance $L$ to reach mirror at $A'$ again.
$L>\ell$ and the speed of light is constant so a "tick" for the moving "clock" takes longer than a "tick" for the stationary clock but not of course an observer moving with the clock.

Fairly elementary Mathematics can be used to quantify the magnitude of the difference in the length of the "ticks".

Answer (score 1):

Try this  way of thinking about it.

In space there are three dimensions, but they don't have absolute directions. There is no universal 'up' direction, for  example. Spacetime has four dimensions, and again they don't have absolute directions. In particular, there is no universal time direction. If you and I are stationary relative to each other in space, then we move through spacetime in the same time direction. However, if we start moving relative to each other in space, then we move in different time directions. Specifically, your time axis and mine become tilted relative to each other, the degree of tilt depending on our relative speed.

From your perspective, 'now' is a level slice through spacetime at right angles to your time axis, which we call a 'plane of simultaneity' so if it is 10am on your watch it is 10am everywhere on your plane of simultaneity.

I have exactly the same perspective. If it is 10am on my watch, it is 10am everywhere on my plane of simultaneity.

Now, because your time axis and mine are tilted relative to each other, our planes of simultaneity are tilted too. So your plane of simultaneity- which is a level slice through spacetime in your frame- is actually a sloping slice through spacetime in my frame. The slope is upwards in time in your direction of travel, so where it is 10am everywhere along your plane, it is a gradually increasing time in my frame in the direction you are traveling, and a gradually reducing time in the opposite direction.

It is this tilt in our planes of simultaneity that causes time dilation. As you move through my frame, you find that my local time become progressively more out of synch with yours. So you might leave me at 10am, say, and after traveling for a minute it is 10:01 in your watch, but because you have been travelling up a slope in time in my frame, it might be 10:02 say on a nearby clock A in my frame, so your watch will seem to have lost a minute compared with that clock. If you wait another minute it will be 10:02 on your watch, but on the clock you are now passing in my frame, clock B, the time will be 10:04, so you now seem to have lost two minutes.

By comparing your watch against a series of different clocks in my frame, it seems to be falling further and further behind. But that is not because your watch is ticking more slowly than my clocks- it is because my clocks are out of synch in your frame. When you left me at 10am, in your frame my clock A was *already showing 10:01, and my clock B was already showing 10:02*. So a minute then ticked on your watch while you moved from me to clock A, and a minute also ticked on clock A, and when you reach clock A it reads 10:02 and your watch reads 10:01, not because your watch ticked slow but because clock A was already a munite ahead when you left me.

So hopefully you can see that time dilation is not an effect that causes clocks to run slow- instead it is  an effect that arises from time in one frame being out of synch with time in another.

Comment: Please respond to me. After reading your message I concluded that relative speed is reason of time dilation. Is it right?

Comment: @Mike_bb no, the reason is the _finite and constant speed of light_.  That is why you don't get anything like gamma from Newtonian physics - there is no time dilation there.